# How do I do a Simple Scan in DynamoDB?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Trying to understand the docs has been very difficult in relation to trying to understand how to do a simple scan in AWS DynamoDB.

Can someone please explain to me in simple terms how to do a basic scan?

Answer (score 0):

#### What is a Scan?

---

> The Scan operation returns one or more items and item attributes by accessing every item in a table or a secondary index.

**Explanation**

- A `scan` operation in it's simplest form looks through everything in your table. Most of the time, you probably don't need the whole table to be returned or even looked at. As a result, many often decide to use filters to cut down on the stuff to look through, process and return.

#### How do I Scan?

---

- Here is a simple scan operation in `python`. Even if you aren't using python, this guide will be very helpful.

```py
# Table = 'grades'
# Year_levels = {0-12}
# Sort_key = overall_rank
# Attribute_categories = math, english, science | out of 100

import boto3                                       
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')                      
table = dynamodb.Table("grades")

result = table.scan(   

    FilterExpression ='math > :math AND english > :eng',       
    ExpressionAttributeValues = {':math': 80,':eng': 70},    

    Select='SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES',  
    ProjectionExpression='year_level,overall_rank,math,english',
    
    Limit = 50                                                      #This is the amount of items to SCAN, not necessarily RETURN.
)
# return or print result
```

**Explanation**

- `FilterExpression and ExpressionAttributeValues`. There are multiple ways of understanding how these work. One way to understand it is by seeing it as an item `attribute` `value` checker. In other words, every item that the `scan` goes through, the filter's applied upon it's `attributes` must be true for the item to be returned. e.g (a math score of 80%+ and an english score of 70%+)
- `Select and Projection Expression`. In technical terms, the way in which I explain this is incorrect, however, in practical terms this way of understanding holds up: You can see that there is a SECOND filter, not for the item, but the ATTRIBUTES of the item that will be returned. e.g (I only want the
  year_level, overall_rank, math, english to be returned, but no science)
- Now if we combine the two we have an example: If an item is checked and matches the criteria placed upon it by the `FilterExpression`, it will be returned. HOWEVER, we only want `SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES` to be returned. At this point, the item will then be checked AGAIN against, this time, the `Select` criteria. The select criteria tells you what attributes FROM the item to return.
- `Limit` is just the amount of items to check through, but not necessarily return.

[References](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html)

[References](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.scan)